# Azure Blob Copy issue

Tags: azure, blob, azure-cli

I'm trying to copy from azure blob with this command:

`az storage blob download-batch --destination / --source my-continer --pattern "my/pattern/here/*"`

to the `/` path, yet it copies the entire blob path.
So in `/` I see `my/pattern/here` structure instead of just the content of `/here` folder

Is there a way to override this behavior and make it copy just the path that matches the pattern that I entered?

Comment: When you say "blob path" - fyi blob storage doesn't have the concept of directories. It just has containers and objects. If you have longer paths (e.g. `my/pattern/here`) that's actually part of the blob name itself.

Comment: Ok so i'll rephrase - can I drop some of the blob path and get only the pattern that I have requested?

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's impossible that just download blobs without the path `my/pattern/here` through the CLI command `az storage blob download-batch`. See screenshot of the blob:

[image]

Its name shows with the path, it means you download the blob with name my/pattern/name to the current directory locally. Then in Linux, the name means that it will create the directories until there is no `/`.

So I suggest you can use the CLI command [`az storage blob download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) to download the files with a loop.

Comment: i'll try that, thanks.
I've also heard about rclone as a possible solution